# when navigating to localhost:3000, navigate to localhost:3000/workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

When navigating to `localhost:3000`, I want to navigate to: `localhost:3000/workers`.

So I changed `public/index.html` to `public/index.html.bak` and in `routes.rb`, I defined the next followings:

```
devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end

resources :tasksadmins

resources :workers

root to: "workers#index"
```

However, it doesn't work. The page `localhost:3000` shows me the Welcome aboard page.

How can I fix it? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine. Have you restarted the server?